# define a method with a vector of templates as an argument

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a method in my C++11 code that accepts a template as an argument

```
template<typename type> uint64_t insert(type item) {
    //code
    return id; 
 }
```

and I want to create a similar in order to insert many items. My attempt was to pass these items as a vector. However the compilation failed with error "**error: template argument 1 is invalid**"

```
template<typename type> std::vector<uint64_t> insert_many(std::vector<type insta> items) {

   std::vector<uint64_t> v;
  //v.push_back(...)
  //code
  return v; 
}
```

What is wrong with the above method signature?

Comment: What is `type insta` ?

Comment: `insert_many(const std::vector<type>& items)`, don't copy your vector.

Comment: `std::vector<type insta>` is a syntax error, did you mean `std::vector<type>` ?

Comment: There is no such thing as a vector of templates. There are function templates and class templates in C++, and neither can be an element of a vector.

Comment: please be more careful with your wording. A method cannot take a template as parameter. `type` is not a template, it is the template parameter, ie once you instantiate the template for some concrete type, eg `int`, then `type` will be this concrete type

Comment: Your code compiles correctly since the edit, except that `id` is not defined. Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you are still having trouble

Comment: please dont fix your code in the question after you got comments on it. Now your code does not match the error you report. Fixed code should go into the answer section. You should roll the edit back, otherwise the question is rather pointless

Comment: @user463035818 rollbacked the question. The problem was the word after the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `type` is the type of the objects you store in your vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename type>
typename std::vector<type>::iterator insert(std::vector<type>& v, const std::vector<type>& add) {
    return v.insert(v.end(), add.begin(), add.end());
}


int main() {
    std::vector<int> a{0,1,2,3,4};
    std::vector<int> b{5,6};
    insert(a, b);
    for(const auto val : a) {
        std::cout << val << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
```